# Rendering Quake BSP's in modern OpenGL and C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm looking for a few tutorials, or even books, with current or at least, non-pre-2000 information about rendering BSPs in OpenGL and C++. Most stuff i found is quite outdated and not suited for beginners. Do you guys recommend anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSP are a common but old data structure, I don't think that there is too much interest this days for a plain old BSP, however you can play with it in blender since there is an [interesting plugin](http://andyp123.blogspot.it/2013/06/blender-quake-bsp-importer.html) for you, so you could maybe open it and study the code ( It's python ).

You can probably look at some 3D resource related to 3D rendering engines, the ones used in 3D art production's pipelines, they are often similar if not identical to what is used in realtime applications.

Comment: The most unfortunate thing about Quake 1-3, is that the file format they use for level geometry, lightmaps, etc. (IBSP) is called `.bsp` I believe this is what the OP is referring to, since as you mentioned in your answer the BSP data structure is relatively standard.